# CSS File not Loaded

Tags: css

I have the following file and directory structure

[image]

In practice.html I have

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Practice</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
      <p>Paragraph</p>
      <h1>Heading</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in styles.css I have

```
p {
    font-family: "Ubuntu", "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
}

h1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: red;
}
```

I've been staring at this for a while.  None of my browsers render using the css styles.  How can I figure out what the problem is?  I can see in Chrome that the css file is not being loaded, but I can't tell why.

I'm a C++ programmer venturing into the scary world of web.  Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Could it be your adblocker?

Comment: In your browser could you view the page source by pressing `Ctrl + U`? Click on the link to your CSS file to see if it does get loaded.

Comment: Do you see any errors in the chrome console?

Comment: I don't see any errors in Chrome but I'm not sure exactly where to look.  A "hard load" did not fix it.  It also does not work in Incognito mode with no extensions.

Comment: Me and Web are going to get along great.

Comment: If I put this into chrome `file:///Users/xyz/my-smarter-site/css/styles.css` then chrome displays the contents of the stubborn css file.

Comment: I wonder if it doesn't like relative paths to local files... I'd try hosting it on some free webhosting site with ftp just to play around with it.

Comment: Also, don't let this discourage you. :D The web is a great place to get things done, and think. You never have to deal with Visual Studio!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a real time waster.  It turns out that the code `<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css"/>`, which I copied from a macOS iBook, contained the unicode character for [non-breaking whitespace](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00a0/index.htm) instead of the standard space character.  When I looked at these in hex mode they were `c2a0`.  Replacing these with `20` fixed the problem.

What I find disappointing is that neither Firefox nor Chrome reported that anything was going wrong during the parsing of the html.

Also note that pasting the code into Stack Overflow seems to have normalized these non-breaking spaces to the more common `20` spaces, so nobody could have reproduced my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing is wrong with your code. Whenever you're doing this type of simple web dev stuff, always hard refresh your windows (Ctrl + F5 on Windows, Opt + Cmd + E on Mac).

I can't tell you the amount of times I thought I was doing something wrong only to realize I wasn't hard refreshing and a change was not being read.

Comment: Good thought, though I don't think the HTML would be cached like this. We'll see I guess. Another good thing to activate is an option in Chrome to not cache while development tools are open.

Answer (score 0):

I might recommend coding in Incognito so local scripts will load faster.

When you using chrome also try to hard refresh (CTRL+SHIFT+R) at the same time so you would see the changes being done immediately

Goodluck!